# Python decrypted text is different every time I decrypt

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, rsa

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
import ast
file_in = open("secret.bin", "rb")

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
   [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]

# Decrypt the session key with the private RSA key
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

# Decrypt the data with the AES session key
cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
t=data.decode("ascii",'ignore')
t= ast.literal_eval(t)
print (t)
for items in t:
      print(items," = ",t[items])
```

On my PC it works fine and whenever I decrypt it gives the same text back.
But on my server the result is different every time. Some parts are missing or are in the wrong place. The packages are all updated and installed.